# testing a jest mock function itself

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I was trying to test a mock function by printing its return value on console.
This is the setup -

The Service which is being mocked (just a copy of Fetch)-

```
export default function FetchService(url){
return fetch(url);
}
```

This is my mock function setup (inside the__mocks__ folder) -

```
const  posts= [
      { "id": 1, "Name": "pen", "Stock": "100" },
      { "id": 2, "Name": "pencil", "Stock": "150" }
    ]


export default  function FetchService(url){
return  new Promise((resolve)=>{
Promise.resolve(posts)
})
     }
```

So if I the mock function works fine, the promise should resolve and always return the predefined array of 2 objects, right?

Keeping that in mind, I wrote the following test case -

```
jest.mock('./FetchService');
test('getting data',(done)=>{

    let returnedData=[];
    FetchService('').then((data)=>data.json()).then((dataP)=>{
        returnedData=dataP;     
    });

    setTimeout(()=>{console.log(returnedData);done();},2000);    
})
```

Problem is , the the consoloe.log shows that the 'returnedData' is empty array instead of what I expected.

What am I missing here?
Please let me know if I can provide some more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first your mock is never resolved, because you don't call passed `resolve` callback, and second is that mock should return object with `json` method, which should return promise:

```
export default  function FetchService(url) {
  const json = () => Promise.resolve( posts );
  return  new Promise( resolve => resolve({ json }));
}
```

Also, you can call `done()` directly in `.then` (maybe just simpler without `setTimeout`):

```
test('getting data',(done)=>{
  FetchService('')
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(
      data => {
        expect(data).toHaveLength(2);
        done();     
  });
})
```